# How to change image element class with JavaScript based on window width?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to adjust the size of a background image based on the width of the window. I have been testing this, and I can get the alerts to show up in chrome when I 'inspect element' and change the width size, and the alerts show up as they should. But I cannot get the class of the image to change.

Any ideas?

**This is my basefunctions.js file**

```
window.onload = function changeClass(){
    if( window.innerWidth < 770 ) {
      document.getElementById("bg_img").setAttribute("class", "imgMobile");
      alert("On Mobile");
    }else{
      alert("Not on Mobile");
    }
}
```

**This is my HTML/CSS**

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="js/basefunctions.js"></script>

<style>

#bg_img {
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    border: 1px #000 solid;
    height:80%;
}

.imgMobile {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    margin-left: -100;
}

</style>

<img src="img/gavel.png" alt="" id="bg_img" class="">
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `className` rather than using `setAttribute`.

```
document.getElementById("bg_img").className = "imgMobile";
```

[Here is another SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-class-with-javascript) about changing an dom object's class.

I also put together a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ahgxs6n2/) to demonstrate.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that too, not sure why it's not working. I have it set to display:none and the margin changing just to verify that it's working, but the image didn't change at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the class using

```
document.getElementById("bg_img").className = "imgMobile";
```

If you want to add the class without overriding other classes, then use

```
document.getElementById("bg_img").className += " imgMobile";
```